# Can we put OR condition in @CsvBindByName annotation to read multiple CSV files

Tags: java

I have to read multiple CSV files and some CSV files, column name are different and values also different.

**Example-:**

CSV1 -:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| FirstNameL | LastNameL |
```

CSV2 -:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| First_Name | Last_Name |
```

CSV3 -:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| FirstNameL | LastNameL |
```

I want to read both column name from single bean class (something like -: @CsvBindByName(column = "FirstNameL" OR  column = "First_Name")

```
public class Test {
@CsvBindByName(column = "FirstNameL")
private String first_Name ;

@CsvBindByName(column = "LastNameL")
private String last_Name;

//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: In your example, I don't see column names being different, instead, "Column A | Column B" are the same for all files. What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
@CsvBindAndJoinByName(column = "FirstNameL,FirstName")
private String first_Name;
```